# How to add bitbucket docs to readthedocs

Tags: bitbucket, read-the-docs

I have a private bitbucket repo which contains:

```
/docs
/docs/source
/docs/Makefile
/docs/make.bat/
/docs/source/conf.py
/docs/source/index.rst
```

I want to add this documentation to readthedocs( i have set up the hook in bitbucket) but when it tries to build it says

```
Failed to get code from 'https://bitbucket.org/autokada/autokada.git' (git clone): 128
```

What is wrong and how to do this corectly?

In addition this was all done manualy adding the repo to redthedocs though i have added bitbucket to my social accounts in readthedocs bet when i try to import from bitbucket it says there is nothing and when i try to sync up then this happens:

```
           .
     ":"
   ___:____     |"\/"|
 ,'        `.    \  /
 |  O        \___/  |
~^~^~^~^~^~^~^~^~^~^~^~^~

Fail.  Check back in a bit!
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm having the same issues

Answer (score 2):

ReadtheDocs does not support private repositories. [Developer's answer](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/1144):

> We aren't looking to support private repositories with readthedocs.org, we only offer hosting for open source projects. Github and Bitbucket private repository support is built into readthedocs.com

Comment: This answer seems contradictory. And removing the `private` flag from the repository in BitBucket, thereby making it public, doesn't appear to be a solution.

Comment: @TomRussell I created one project in january 2016 with a public Bitbucket repository, you can check it on: http://paradigmas1.readthedocs.io/ and the repo is here: https://bitbucket.org/rafa/paradigmas/overview. You should verify, maybe you overlooked something.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a Bitbucket newb. I unchecked the "private repository" box in a bitbucket repository and everything magically wired itself up correctly. Strong magic.